# Html5 mobile app vs email & SMS

Tags: android, ios, html, email, sms

Is there a way to show native email/SMS send interface from the html5 web-page?
or should I create my native adapter and call it every time I need to send something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is all you intended to ask, but if you only want to show the native interfaces for these, this should do the trick.

For the email just use something like:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">E-mail user@example.com</a>
```

As for a phone number:

```
<a href="tel:1234567890">Call 1234567890</a>
```

For sms:

```
<a href="sms:1234567890">Send a message to 1234567890</a>
```

If you want you can also include a subject and/or body for the email like this:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?subject=Story&body=Once upon a time...">user@example.com</a>
```

Including a body in a sms:

```
<a href="sms:1234567890?body=Hello">Send Hello via SMS to 1234567890</a>
```

Comment: seems like this way in ios has some problem when the body content is too long or contain some special character